# Installing LYX&TexLive on Linux Mint 17 with Hebrew support

Tags: lyx, texlive, ubuntu, linux

I'm trying to run install-tl-ubuntu script with "--hebrew" option, then install the LYX package from the repos. When I run install-tl-ubuntu I get the following error (see the original on http://pastebin.com/cQTyhK1q ):

```
~/texliveinst/install-tl-ubuntu $ sudo ./install-tl-ubuntu --hebrew
install-tl-ubuntu: WARNING: this script currently supports Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10, 13.04, 13.10, and 14.04. 
For other versions, one would probably want to use a different 
debian-control-texlive-in.txt file.
install-tl-ubuntu: checking for TeX Live environment variables...
install-tl-ubuntu: running apt and dpkg commands...
install-tl-ubuntu: determining the fastest repository...
install-tl-ubuntu: the fastest repo is: http://www.cstug.cz/ctan/index.html
install-tl-ubuntu: downloading and extracting install-tl for time number 1...

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
install-tl-ubuntu: WARNING: tar failed
install-tl-ubuntu: we will try to restart the download/extract.
install-tl-ubuntu: downloading and extracting install-tl for time number 2...

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
install-tl-ubuntu: WARNING: tar failed
install-tl-ubuntu: we will try to restart the download/extract.
install-tl-ubuntu: downloading and extracting install-tl for time number 3...

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
install-tl-ubuntu: WARNING: tar failed
install-tl-ubuntu: we will try to restart the download/extract.
install-tl-ubuntu: downloading and extracting install-tl for time number 4...

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
install-tl-ubuntu: WARNING: tar failed
install-tl-ubuntu: we will try to restart the download/extract.
install-tl-ubuntu: downloading and extracting install-tl for time number 5...

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
install-tl-ubuntu: WARNING: tar failed
install-tl-ubuntu: we will try to restart the download/extract.
install-tl-ubuntu: downloading and extracting install-tl for time number 6...

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
install-tl-ubuntu: WARNING: tar failed
install-tl-ubuntu: we will try to restart the download/extract.
install-tl-ubuntu: downloading and extracting install-tl for time number 7...

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
install-tl-ubuntu: WARNING: tar failed
install-tl-ubuntu: we will try to restart the download/extract.
install-tl-ubuntu: downloading and extracting install-tl for time number 8...

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
install-tl-ubuntu: WARNING: tar failed
install-tl-ubuntu: we will try to restart the download/extract.
install-tl-ubuntu: downloading and extracting install-tl for time number 9...

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
install-tl-ubuntu: WARNING: tar failed
install-tl-ubuntu: we will try to restart the download/extract.
install-tl-ubuntu: downloading and extracting install-tl for time number 10...

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
install-tl-ubuntu: WARNING: tar failed
install-tl-ubuntu: we will try to restart the download/extract.
install-tl-ubuntu: downloading and extracting install-tl for time number 11...

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
install-tl-ubuntu: WARNING: tar failed
install-tl-ubuntu: ERROR: install-tl failed to download/extract 11 times. Aborting.
install-tl-ubuntu: ERROR: cannot find install-tl dir to cd into.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's better to post error messages directly, not as images or links to another websites

Comment: I thought it would be better not to do that because the terminal's output is long and repetitive. I won't do it again next time. Got an idea on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer:
use

```
sudo ./install-tl-ubuntu --hebrew --repository "REPO"
```

Where REPO is one chosen from here:
http://www.ctan.org/mirrors/

More details:
When a mirror is not working correctly, I do not see a robust way to detect it. I thought that bad mirrors were removed, as stated on the mirrors page:

> Mon­i­tor­ing of the Mir­rors
>
> We mon­i­tor mir­rors to check that they are up to date. If a mir­ror falls be­hind then mirror.ctan.org will not redi­rect to it, and it is not listed on this page.

Comment: Note that REPO must be provided in a form similar to:  
`ftp://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan`  
  
  
For example:  
`sudo ./install-tl-ubuntu --hebrew -q ftp://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan`